# How can I animate a set of points imported from file?

Tags: plotting, import, manipulate, animation

I have an external program which generates a set of data - X points at the time t1, X points at the time t2 and so on. These points are stored in CSV file and I can change the format if necessary.
What is the easiest way to plot and manipulate them, so I can click "play" and see the dynamics of process?

**UPD:**
For example, points at t1:

```
0.2 42.8
0.4 12.3
0.6 32.1
0.8 37.3
```

Points at t2:

```
0.2 44.2
0.4 17.8
0.6 39.0
0.8 30.1
```

It is always a constant number of points at any time (4 in example). I can export them to separate CSV files or in the one file and change format in any way necessary, like adding a new column.

Comment: Welcome, Andrew.  Please consider posting a small sample of your data, or a representative approximation.  Also, what kind of plot do you desire?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks, I have updated the question. Line plot.

Comment: You could, you know, do something like `Map[ListPlot, {t1Points, t2Points, ...}]` and then use `ListAnimate[]` on those...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Load your data with `Import["data.csv"]` and process as necessary into:

```
data = {
  {{0.2`, 42.8`}, {0.4`, 12.3`}, {0.6`, 32.1`}, {0.8`, 37.3`}},
  {{0.2`, 44.2`}, {0.4`, 17.8`}, {0.6`, 39.`},  {0.8`, 30.1`}}
  };
```

Build a sequence of plots with a fixed `PlotRange` to stabilize the image, and `ListAnimate`:

```
ListAnimate[
   ListLinePlot[#, PlotRange -> {10, 50}] & /@ data
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Andrew you're welcome.  Please make your future questions as specific as possible, and include sample data and executable code when appropriate.

Answer (score 21):

Then add some salt

```
q = 20;
pos = Table[.1 i, {i, q}];
{start, end} = RandomReal[1, {2, q}];
pts[i_Integer, t_Real] := {pos[[i]], (1 - t) start[[i]] + t end[[i]]}
c[t_Real] := Interpolation[Table[pts[i, t], {i, q}], Method -> "Spline"];

Manipulate[
  Plot[c[t][x], {x, 0.1, 2},
   PlotRange -> {{0, 2.1}, {-.5, 1.2}},
   Epilog -> {
     Red,   PointSize[0.01], Point@Table[pts[i, t], {i, q}],
     Green, Line@Partition[Riffle[Transpose[{pos, start}], Transpose[{pos, end}]], 2]
     }],
  {t, 0.01, .99, .05}]
```

[image]

**Edit**

Found some code I used in a project eons ago. You could do very weird things with your points' trajectories if you take some precautions:

```
(*Let's create a points file sample *)
s = Transpose@Table[{i + Cos[2 Pi k/10], Sin[2 Pi i/10] + Sin[2 Pi (k + 3)/10]}, 
                   {i, 0, 10, 1.}, {k, 0, 10, 1.}];
Export["c:\\table.csv", Flatten[s, 1]];
ClearAll[s];
```

> 

```
    (*Main fun def*)
maniPointPlot[pts_, n_] := Module[{sets, steps, curve, pp, enlarge, bounds, apt},

   sets = MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #1} &, Partition[pts, n], {2}];(*Add time indicator*)
   bounds = {Min@#, Max@#} & /@ Transpose@pts;(*Bounds for Plot*)
   steps = Length@sets;(*Time span*)

   (*Memoize Positions of point # over time " / All Points Together*)
   apt[t_] := apt[t] = Interpolation[#, Method -> "Spline"][t] & /@ Transpose@sets;
   (*Curve at time t*)
   curve[t_] := Interpolation[apt@t, Method -> "Spline"];

   (*aux func for interval dilation*)
   enlarge[{a_, b_}] := {a - #, b + #} &@(Abs[b - a]/10);
   (*Green Points traces*)
   pp = ParametricPlot[apt@t, {t, 1, steps}, ColorFunction -> (Green &)];

   (*Our little beast follows*)
   Manipulate[
    Show@{Plot[curve[t][x], Evaluate@{x, Sequence@@bounds[[1]]}, PlotRange -> enlarge /@ bounds],
          Graphics[Point@apt@t],
          pp}, {t, 1, steps}]];
```

> 

```
(*Now your code*)

s = Import["c:\\table.csv"]; (*Read the table*)
nbr = 11; (*number of points in each set*)
Off[InterpolatingFunction::dmval];
maniPointPlot[s, nbr]
```

[image]

Cozy crawling cardioids:

[image]

Comment: And don't forget the bacon... because everything is better with bacon.

Comment: @jmlopez I was going to said something about the beer. Byt i"n two drjnk tp rimemver wat uas itjs/

Comment: Que? lol, I should go grab one too...

Comment: Okay that's pretty slick. +1

Comment: [Are you a wizard?](http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4119/4876696414_d3f62d18be_z.jpg)